# Max characters/lines for an HTML page

Tags: html, char, size, limit

I have a page with a lot of includes (it is a CMS).
Somehow, after some updates and new codes pushed onto the server, the page does not load entirely.
Everything after line 2548 is like being ignored on Chrome + Firefox (IE not tested).

Is there any limit to an HTML page?
Else,
what do you suggest? Maybe to see the server configuration?

Source code for page admin.php

> ```
> <div class="panel">
> <div id="stats" class="panel-collapse collapse bloc-deroulant-menu">   
> <?php include('donnees/stats.php');
>   include('page/stats.php'); ?>
> </div>
> </div>
> ```

And source code of the page in browser:

> ```
>   <div class="panel">
> <div id="stats" class="panel-collapse collapse bloc-deroulant-menu">
> ```

EDIT: Added Source code. It is source code at around line 2548
Includes are correctly uploaded on the server.
Includes source code checked and no error found

Thank you!

Comment: What's on line 2548 ? Probably there is an error around there. I don't think there is a max page size.

Comment: I added source code to original post

Comment: Can you post lines 2540-2560?

Answer (score 0):

My bad.
The error comes indeed from the includes.
It is now solved.

Thank you for everything